# How to store 8 or more inherited .net type in relelational Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, inheritance, relational-database, ef-core-3.1

I have one base Column class and other column types derived from this type but derived types may be increased lot more.
I don't want to use the TPH approach because of the lots of unrelated column count.
Other 2 approach (TPC and TPT) is also problematic because EF core not supported yet.
What do you recommend storing this kind of information in RDBMS?

```
public class Column
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public ColumnType ColumnType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}

public class HyperLinkColumn : Column
{
    public UrlFormatType UrlFormatType { get; set; }
}
public class YesNoColumn : Column
{
    public bool DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
public class DateTimeColumn : Column
{
    private DateTime _defaultValue;
    public DateTimeFormat DateTimeFormat { get; set; }
    public string DisplayFormat { get; set; }
    public bool IsValueDateTimeNow { get; set; }

    public DateTime DefaultValue
    {
        get => _defaultValue;
        set
        {
            if (IsValueDateTimeNow)
                _defaultValue = DateTime.Now;

            _defaultValue = value;
        }
    }
}
public class CurrencyColumn : NumberColumn
{
    public string CurrencyFormat { get; set; }
}
public class NumberColumn : NumericColumn
{
    public bool ShowLikePercentage { get; set; }
}
public abstract class NumericColumn : Column
{
    public int MinValue { get; set; }
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }
    public decimal DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfDecimalPlace { get; set; }
}
public class ChoiceColumn : Column
{
    public List<string> Options { get; set; }
    public ChoiceType ChoiceType { get; set; }
    public bool AllowFillInChoice { get; set; }
}
public class MultiLineOfTextColumn : Column
{
    public int NumberOfLineAllowed { get; set; }
    public TextType TextType { get; set; }
}
public class SingleLineTextColumn : Column
{
    public int MaxNumberOfCharacter { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to use the TPH approach because of the lots of unrelated
>   column count.

But data will be in one place and you avoid any joins.

> What do you recommend storing this kind of information in RDBMS?

I saw metadata stored as `XML` or `JSON in text column` and that information was deserialized later in app. It wasnt that bad because data was cached in memory.

`TPH` looks fine to me though

Answer (score 1):

> What do you recommend storing this kind of information in RDBMS?

TPH or a JSON column with a [Value Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

The worst thing about TPH is not the null columns per se.  It's knowing and enforcing which columns are applicable to which subtypes.  And EF mostly fixes that, as the Entity model enforces which subtypes get which properties.  EF Core has been slow to implement TPT *precisely because* TPH is the recommended model.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the answer. But this will also cause another problem when SPA or another client app posts a list of columns serializer doesn't recognize the valid CLR type and then deserializes incoming JSON as a base type for all derived types, in this case, every derived type will be Column itself

Comment: This makes me use serialization with type info and this is another smell I think. I enforce client to passes the type info along with the actual object info